# android unBindService callback service

Tags: android, service

In Android services, when we call `bindService` , `onServiceConnected` will be triggered where I can get the service instance. But, when I call `unBindService` or `stopService`, `onServiceDisconnected` will never be triggered. As per the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceDisconnected(android.content.ComponentName)), `onServiceDisconnected` will only be called when the app gets killer or crashed. So, where should I expect a callback when `unBindService` is done? I want to to call `stopService` only when `unBind` is done.

As these both `unBindService` and `stopService` are async calls, I cannot call `stopService` just after calling `unBindService`. Because `stopService` might get finished before `unBindService` which leaves me with `Service not registered exception`.

All the Android services docs and tutorials instructs `mBound` state, where we need to maintain this boolean when service gets stopped or started. But still then, the above problem exists.

My question is, how can I implement `unBindService` callback? and Is calling `unBindService` after `stopService` might give any exception? If so when should we call it?

Comment: why dont you use auto create flag when binding to the service?

Comment: When you unbind from a bound service, you shouldn't stop the service as other app components may require it to keep running. That's the design goal.

Comment: Yes ! I will rethink my design. Thanks for the comments! @Squonk

Comment: dont call startService, just bindService with auto create flag

Comment: @pskink Yeah, but in some cases, I don't want to auto-create the service while binding. Thanks for your time!

Comment: what do you mean? so what do you want?